# Loop doesn't continue to run when checking for keywords on websites

Tags: c#, arraylist

I'm using my class to get the website ID in my database, hence the `gd.Get(i)`

I then want to download the HTML from the URL, which I'm doing successfully. I then want to strip the HTML and turn into a list of words, making the words which are used most frequently, appearing first.

I'm then wanting to check these keywords and BREAK the loop if one of my keywords are within the list of keywords from the source code.

It seems I have nailed this, partially. For some reason, after finding one keyword which matches `music` or `pop` my code completely stopped running and doesn't go onto the next website. Furthermore, the code seems to be running ridiculously slow.

Anyone who can point out what I'm doing wrong here would be a lifesaver! Thanks

```
    for (int i = 1514; i < ttl; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            gd.Get(i);
            if (gd.Website.Length > 4)
            {

                var website = gd.Website;

                if(!website.Contains("http://") && !website.Contains("https://"))
                {
                    website = "http://" + website;
                }


                string html = "";

                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    html = client.DownloadString(website).ToLower();
                }

                html = RemoveHtmlTags(html);

                List<string> list = html.Split(' ').ToList();

                int countWords = list.Count;

                var onlyAlphabetRegEx = new Regex(@"^[A-z]+$");
                list = list.Where(f => onlyAlphabetRegEx.IsMatch(f)).ToList();

                //add your own
                string[] blacklist = { "a", "your", "an", "on", "of", "or", "as", "i", "in", "is", "to", "the", "and", "for", "with", "not", "by" };
                list = list.Where(x => x.Length > 2).Where(x => !blacklist.Contains(x)).ToList();

                var keywords = list.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count());

                foreach (var word in keywords)
                {

                    string[] kws = { "music", "pop" };
                    for (int d = 0; d < kws.Length; i++)
                    {
                        bool contains = word.Key.ToString().IndexOf(kws[d], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;

                        if (contains == true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(website + " contains "+kws[d]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }                        
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(gd.Title+" has no website.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

Edit: Added `RemoveHtmlTags` as requested.

```
public static string RemoveHtmlTags(string html)
{
    string htmlRemoved = Regex.Replace(html, @"<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?</script>|<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", " ").Trim();
    string normalised = Regex.Replace(htmlRemoved, @"\s{2,}", " ");
    return normalised;
}
```

Comment: What is `RemoveHtmlTags` ?

Comment: `Furthermore, the code seems to be running ridiculously slow` try looking into `Task`'s and or `TPL` to do this work. Further look into `async` as well... Also `HTMLAgilityPack` is a great parser that will do the parsing of your `html`...[You](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) can grab that here as a Nuget package.

Comment: I suggest you to use a proper HTML parser

Comment: Finally, can you please show us how you are using this code and or calling it? There's other improvements to be made, specifically your `linq` statements etc.. but not of concern as why your code just stops running.

Comment: @Cid, I've added that - sorry!

Comment: **Not HtmlAgilityPack!** Use AngleSharp instead.